# Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ByteArray, yet it's imported

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors, arrays, flex3, flashdevelop

I'm new to ActionScript and Flash.

I wrote the following class and imported anothery a util class called "ByteArray".

This is my code:

```
package com.brokenfunction.json
{
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public const decodeJson:Function = initDecodeJson();
}

function initDecodeJson():Function
{
    var position:uint = 0;
    var byteInput:ByteArray = null;
    var char:uint = 0;
    var nativeJson:Object = null;
}
.....
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

```
C:\Desktop\..\decodeJson.as(11): col: 18 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ByteArray.
   var byteInput:ByteArray = null
                 ^
```

Why is this happening? I have imported the "flash.utils.ByteArray"
Is there any issue with my SDK version? ("Flex SDK 4.6")
Am I missing the class in my SDK?

Thanks for answers

Comment: If your method initDecodeJson is outside class definition than you need to import it again. The one you imported was within package

Comment: I have imported "flash.utils.ByteArray" into all og my classes. Yet i'm recieving the same error..

Comment: You are not reading correctly the first comment, read it again and then apply what was said. Since for some reason you like to define methods outside package scope then you need to make sure the imported class are in scope outside the package. Better yet stop defining methods outside package scope, it has literally no advantages whatsoever to do that.